# Android Q Desktop Mode - control secondary display

Tags: external-display, mouse, android-beta-program, android-10

I tried new **Desktop Mode** on Android Q Beta 3. The problem is that I'm not able to move mouse pointer to second display, so I don't have any way to use Desktop Mode.

`Google Pixel XL`, display is `ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC`, connected throught HUB via DisplayLink presenter (with USB-A)

*Question:* **How to move mouse pointer to secondary display?**

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt I'm using Google Pixel XL

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that Android Q with it's Desktop Mode is still very much in beta and not a finished product at all.

There's still lots of bugs and problems with it.

The best you can do is wait for the official release later this year.